# Получение данных серверов методом POST

Tags: java, веб-сервер

Пишу веб-сервер на Java (не используя сервлет и т.п.). Получая запрос, я считываю его и тут же вывожу в консоль. Надо получить и обработать POST запрос от браузера после заполнения в нём какой-то формы (не вижу пока смысла прикладывать её код, но если понадобится, выложу). Проблема в том, что у меня в консоли не выводятся никакие данные, веденные пользователем в браузере, а значит я (сервер) просто из не получаю. Или нет?

```
private static Scanner input = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

private static void getAnswer() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("<server> getting answer");
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        request.add(line);
        if (line == null || line.length() == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("exit");
}
```

Пример вывода в консоль:

```
<server> getting answer
POST /forms/formPOST.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 113
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://localhost
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost/forms/formPOST.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

Comment: Вам, по-моему,  условие в блоке if всё ломает - тело запроса отделяется от хедеров пустой строкой, а у вас на пустые строки break стоит

Comment: @fromSPb, а какое тогда условие на выходи из цикла? Ведь проблема в том, что **while(input.hasNextLine())** по сути здесь является **while(true)** , а делать костыль на время запроса плохо, т.к. это сервер.

Comment: откажитесь от Сканнера в пользу, например, BufferedReader. В этом случае даже выиграете, скорее всего, по перформансу.

Comment: и, скорее всего, if (line == null) должно сработать тоже. Пробема, на мой взгляд, только в условии line.length() == 0, которое эвалюэйтится в true, когда в строке есть только "\n".

Comment: @fromSPb ну **if (line == null)** не работает (он тупа ждет след строку и все, зависает). Также, можете, пожалуйста, показать как считывать при помощи BufferedReader, ибо я не вижу у него аналога **while(input.hasNextLine())**. Да и вообще, он вроде должен остановиться, когда встретит "\n", а в моем случае это не конец

Comment: посмотрите, например, здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033755/reading-post-data-from-html-form-sent-to-serversocket